# Does user is charged for using azure managed instance in free trail period?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am new to Azure. I have create Azure free account.
I like to migrate production database to Azure Cloud, and found Managed Instance as perfect choice (as per documentation). Before migration i want test it out, but not sure if this service is free or not.

It shows Subscription as Free Trial and
in Pricing Tier section it shows 16vCore and 32GB Storage selected.

So, my question is that - will i be charged if i create SQL Server Managed Instance in trail period?

Answer (score 0):

While using the trial period your credit card won't be charged. When the trial ends, if the product is still in Preview, you will enjoy that it cost half the price. At the time of GA it will have its full price.

While you use it with the trial account, you may noticed that you cannot create a managed instance in all regions where is currently available. That is normal while you are using the trial/evaluation account.

If you are wrongly charged for any reason, create a billing support ticket which is free. You can also create a billing support ticket to confirm the information here provided.